# Why is my mux not producing an output in Verilog?

Tags: verilog

I've written what I *thought* would be a working MUX, but my output is stubbornly staying at high-impedance. Can someone please provide me with guidance?

```
module mux_in #(parameter WIDTH = 1, parameter LOG_CHOICES = 1)
(
    input  [LOG_CHOICES - 1 : 0] choice,
    input  [(1 << LOG_CHOICES) * WIDTH - 1 : 0] data_i,
    output [WIDTH - 1 : 0] data_o
);
    assign data_o = data_i[WIDTH * choice + WIDTH - 1 : WIDTH * choice];
endmodule
```

Here's my (bad) output:

```
data_i: 11111010101111100001001100100010
data_o: zzzzzzzz
Choice 0: (Expected  34) Output:   z
Choice 1: (Expected  19) Output:   z
Choice 2: (Expected 190) Output:   z
Choice 3: (Expected 250) Output:   z
```

Comment: What simulator is this? Can you post the testbench? Your output does not match the default parameters.

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your question to include the instantiation of your module, so we can see what ports you have connected and what values you have specified for the module parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not compile because the range expression is not constant.

```
assign data_o = data_i[WIDTH * choice + WIDTH - 1 : WIDTH * choice];
```

Try this instead.

```
assign data_o = data_i[WIDTH * choice + WIDTH - 1 -: WIDTH];
```